# order by.... numbers? Help me sort ip addresses

Tags: mysql

MySQL, Trying to get a list of ip addresses, in order.

this query

```
select ip from sn_192_168_0
```

gives this

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101
```

We want

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
...snip..
192.168.0.10
```

Comment: I don't have time to build a full example right now, but what it looks like it's doing is sorting lexicographically (i.e. character-by-character). You'll need to build a SP (or application logic) to force it to sort numerically (i.e. break the IP address into four parts then sort them by each of the parts). Alternatively, instead of breaking it into four parts, make a single integer out of the IP address (first octet of the address = first 8 bits of the number, second octet = second 8 bits and so on) and sort by that - IP addresses are actually nothing more than a well-disguised integer.

Comment: @SimonRigharts that's exactly what it is doing. The general philosophy is that it would be faster (but more space expensive) to convert everything to a large-number field (or use four new fields at 3 characters wide, or three new byte fields) and query off that for sorting, but present this field for display purposes. There are libraries for converting the IP address to a numeric field if you don't want to do the parsing yourself.

Comment: However, since this is really just a code question, booting it to [SO].

Comment: I don't understand why it got moved. "This question came from our site for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community." Is this not relative for someone who wants to improve their database skills?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the [**INET_ATON**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) function

```
SELECT ip FROM sn_192_168_0
ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip);
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : It is best not to store the INET_ATON values. There are some past quirks with this function is you have invalid numbers between dots and calling it in triggers.

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5448
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39386

These bugs are cleaned up now.

Short IP addresses are handled properly. Here is an example from MySQL 5.5.12 in Windows 7

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'), INET_ATON('127.1');
+------------------------+--------------------+
| INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') | INET_ATON('127.1') |
+------------------------+--------------------+
|             2130706433 |         2130706433 |
+------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
SELECT ip FROM sn_192_168_0 ORDER BY LPAD(  ip, 16, 0 )
```

the number 16 is the max length of the ip