# Mysql order by string of a part OR Symbol after some int

Tags: mysql

I have many ip address from MySQL in same table, ip is different segments.

I hope select result like this.
How to use order by ?

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.23
192.168.1.25
192.168.20.1
192.168.20.31
192.168.20.25
192.168.35.2
192.168.35.21
192.168.35.125
```

In Now Mysql_query like this.

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.111
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.23
192.168.1.25
....
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is a truly elegant solution for that, you could put the 4 parts of the IP into four separate columns.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8999436/1618257

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719945/order-by-numbers-help-me-sort-ip-addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like a duplicate question see Legendinmaking's comment above ([order by.... numbers? Help me sort ip addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719945/order-by-numbers-help-me-sort-ip-addresses)).

Polish Prince its post works, but based on the previous post I would recommend this:

```
SELECT ip 
FROM   ips
ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip);
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE ips
    (`ip` varchar(14));

INSERT INTO ips
    (`ip`)
VALUES
    ('192.168.35.2'),
    ('192.168.35.21'),
    ('192.168.1.1'),
    ('192.168.1.2'),
    ('192.168.35.125'),
    ('192.168.1.23'),
    ('192.168.1.25'),
    ('192.168.20.1'),
    ('192.168.20.31'),
    ('192.168.1.10'),
    ('192.168.1.111'),
    ('192.168.20.25');
```

[SQL FIDDLE demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c0b7/3)

Note, that this is based on Polish Prince his SQL Fiddle and Legendinmaking's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
SELECT v.ip 
FROM   (SELECT ip, 
               CAST(Substring_index(ip, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)  first, 
               CAST(Substring_index(Substring_index(ip, '.' 
                   , 2 ), '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)               second, 
               CAST(Substring_index(Substring_index(ip, '.' 
                   , -2 ), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)               third, 
               CAST(Substring_index(ip, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) fourth 
        FROM   ips) v 
ORDER  BY v.first, 
          v.second, 
          v.third, 
          v.fourth
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c0b7/1)