# Display records in ascending order when records are like 12.108.90

Tags: php, mysql

How do I display records in ascending order using PHP/MySQL when the records look like this:

```
12.108.90, 
7.60.109.3,
56.23.45.78.9,
1.7.9.08 ?
```

These records are multiple frequency numbers, and I want to display them in ascending order, but I'm not getting the correct format. My current query looks like this:

```
select * from revision ORDER BY revid DESC
```

The revid records are similar to: `12.8.90`, `7.889.56.90`, `14.78.0`, and `16.67.87.12`. How can I correct the query to sort the records in ascending order?

Comment: what are these records? Definitely not numbers

Comment: please elaborate more, question is not clear

Comment: See this example for sorting IP addresses - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719945/order-by-numbers-help-me-sort-ip-addresses

Comment: these records are some thing like bandwidth numbers, can anyone help me byproviding a query for this

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `usort`.

Eg:

```
$array = array(
     '12.108.90', 
     '7.60.109.3',
     '56.23.45.78.9',
     '1.7.9.08',
);

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
     $a = explode('.', $a);
     $b = explode('.', $b);

     foreach($a as $key => $valuea) {
         if(!isset($b[$key])) {
             return 1;
         }
         $valueb = (int)$b[$key];
         $valuea = (int)$valuea;

         if($valuea === $valueb) {
             continue;
         }

         return $valuea - $valueb;
     }

     return -1;
});

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: these record are some frequency numbers, i want to display these records in ascending order, but iam not getting the corect format, iam using simple query like         (select * from revision where bandwindth='3.5' ORDER BY revid DESC)   the revid records are like    12.8.90,7.889.56.90,14.78.0,16.67.87.12, this query is not working, please suggest me the correct query to solve this problem